# Custom JRE with JavaFX 11

Tags: java, javafx, jlink, javafx-11

I'm Using JDK11 and JavaFX11.

I created a custom JRE for my sample FX module program using Jlink, but when I try to run with the custom JRE, it renders errors as below:

This is how I created my custom JRE (no errors):

```
jlink --module-path ..\jmods;%PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules java.base,java.desktop,jdk.unsupported,javafx.graphics --output FXJRE
```

This is how I tried to run (with errors):

```
FXJRE\bin\java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX%;mods -m com.javafxdemo/com.javafxdemo.JavaFXDemo
```

The error messages:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        ... 5 more
```

Here is how I compiled:

The source JavaFXDemo.java:

```
package com.javafxdemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setLayoutX(100);
        btn.setLayoutY(80);
        btn.setText("Hello World");
        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`module-info.java`:

```
module com.javafxdemo {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    
    exports com.javafxdemo;
}
```

This is how I compiled.

```
javac -d mods\com.javafxdemo --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% src\com.javafxdemo\module-info.java src\com.javafxdemo\com\javafxdemo\JavaFXDemo.java
```

After compilation, I have module class files as below:

```
├───mods
│   └───com.javafxdemo
│       │   module-info.class
│       │
│       └───com
│           └───javafxdemo
│                   JavaFXDemo.class
│
└───src
    └───com.javafxdemo
        │   module-info.java
        │
        └───com
            └───javafxdemo
                    JavaFXDemo.java
```

I can successfully run as below:

```
java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX%;mods -m com.javafxdemo/com.javafxdemo.JavaFXDemo
```

I can run with the default JDK11 though.

How can I successfully create a custom JRE and run the sample FX module program with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to this [link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), you will notice there are two flavors for the JavaFX distribution for each platform:

[image: jmods]

The JavaFX *SDK* is the one you are using as:

```
export PATH_TO_FX=/path/to/javafx-sdk-11/lib
```

and if you check the files under `lib`, these are jars.

The JavaFX *jmods* on the other side contains the jmod format.

And if you read about the `jmod` format [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm):

> For most development tasks, including deploying modules on the module path or publishing them to a Maven repository, continue to package modules in modular JAR files. The **jmod** tool is intended for modules that have native libraries or other configuration files or for modules that you intend to link, with the jlink tool, to a runtime image.

In other words, if you use `javac` or `java` to run your jar or module you can use the SDK, but if you are using `jlink` to create a custom JRE, you need the `jmod` version.

Once you have downloaded the jmods, unzip them and create this variable:

```
export PATH_TO_FX_JMOD=/path/to/javafx-jmods-11/
```

Now you can create the JRE:

```
jlink --module-path %PATH_TO_FX_JMOD%;mods --add-modules=com.javafxdemo --output FXJRE
```

and run:

```
FXJRE/bin/java -m com.javafxdemo/com.javafxdemo.JavaFXDemo
```

Comment: It perfectly answered my question, José Pereda. By the way, do we not need to add **java.base** module when creating a custom JRE?  It was my habit but now, it seems not required.  Are modules automatically added if they are required in the **module-info.java**?

Comment: For jlink you need your module only, you added all the requirements to the module info file.

Comment: Also for module-info you don’t need to add base nor graphics if you are adding controls, as it already depends on them.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04, Java 11, Netbeans 11.0:
I had the same error as you because I set up Library JavaFX11 using the jars in /usr/share/openjfx/lib which are from the Ubuntu openjfx 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 package. I thought because the same jars were in this directory I could use it but the javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib directory you get by downloading JavaFX Linux SDK from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ contains many other library files (like libglass.so) which ARE needed.