# Opening .jar file on mac using JDK 11 fails with RuntimeException

Tags: java, macos, jar, java-11, javafx-11

I am trying to open a .jar file (https://github.com/ptrckbnck/SQLChecker/releases) on my MAC Mojave 10.14 , I need it for my university course.

What I did:

- installed java OpenJDK 11 as suggested here https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/09/28/installing-openjdk-macos/

`java -version`

```
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

But when I run `java -jar SQLChecker-1.0.jar` I keep on getting the following exception:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have read related thread [Migration to JDK 11 + JavaFX 11 giving RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985678/migration-to-jdk-11-javafx-11-giving-runtimeexception) and downloaded also JavaFX 11, namely JavaFX Mac OS X SDK from here https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/. I also run the following code:

```
export PATH_TO_FX=my/path/to/javafx-sdk-11/lib
```

and run HelloWorld test using JavaFX 11 as described here https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. Everything worked fine but did not solve my original problem. 
As was suggested by @Drimux in the related thread some libraries are missing in the OpenJDK distribution. He sad that those probably are libprism_es2.dylib, libprism_sw.dylib, libglass.dylib, libjavafx_font.dylib. So I copied those files from the javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib into /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib and tried to run my .jar file again. Got new exception:

```
GLFactory.static - Platform: Mac OS X - not available: com.sun.prism.es2.MacGLFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.MacGLFactory
at   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory$FactoryLoader.run(GLFactory.java:108)
at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory$FactoryLoader.run(GLFactory.java:100)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.prism.es2.GLFactory.<clinit>(GLFactory.java:97)
at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:76)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacPlatformFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Failed to load Glass factory class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This didn't fix the problem. If you need more information please request. 
What else should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have downloaded the jar from the first test [release](https://github.com/ptrckbnck/SQLChecker/releases/tag/v1.0-alpha), when running it like:

```
java -jar SQLChecker-1.0.jar
```

you will get the posted exception.

As a first easy fix, if you have downloaded JavaFX 11 [SDK](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), run this instead:

```
java --module-path /path-to/javafx-sdk-11/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar SQLChecker-1.0.jar
```

You can read about why you need those VM arguments [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/index.html#install-javafx).

In any case, you shouldn't copy the native files from the JavaFX SDK to the JDK.

**New releases**

But there are two more new releases of SQLChecker.

If you try the last [one](https://github.com/ptrckbnck/SQLChecker/releases/tag/v1.0.3):

```
java -jar SQLChecker-1.0.3.jar
```

that will work fine, without adding those extra arguments.

So what has changed?

They are distributing a fat Jar with the Maven shade plugin, and in order to work on JavaFX 11 on any platform, you need to include not only the jars, but also the native libraries.

As you can see, in this [commit](https://github.com/ptrckbnck/SQLChecker/commit/d289264e8e40ede2a4ca55dd4b7205c54cb12ad2), by including the `classifier` tag for `javafx.graphics`, they added the required native libraries for Windows, Linux and Mac, as it has been also stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing).

If you want to know more about how to create a fat jar, see this [doc](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/index.html#fat-jar).