# Cannot execute JavaFX sample on macOS: No toolkit found

Tags: java, macos, javafx, java-11

When trying to launch the JavaFX "Hello world" sample, the native libraries are not found -- or, they are rejected. The symptom is a "No toolkit found" exception. There seems to be some specificity to macOS, as signing is mentioned at some point.

What I did (on macOS 10.14.6):

1. Installed Java 12 from https://adoptopenjdk.net
2. Downloaded the JavaFX 12 SDK for macOS from http://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-12-0-2-sdk-mac. Unzipped it as `$WRK_DIR/javafx-sdk-12.0.2`
3. Downloaded the JavaFX "hello world" sample from https://github.com/openjfx/samples. Unzipped it as `$WRK_DIR/samples-master`

Then I followed the instructions of the Getting Started ([here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) or [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/CommandLine/Non-modular/CLI/README.md)). I chose the simplest path: no IDE, no build system like Maven, non-modular app, nothing but plain CLI.

```
$ WRK_DIR=$(pwd)
$ ls -lF
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 bruno  staff  128 19 jul 16:25 javafx-sdk-12.0.2/
drwxr-xr-x@ 8 bruno  staff  256 31 jul 10:18 samples-master/
$ PATH_TO_FX=$WRK_DIR/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib
$ ls $PATH_TO_FX 
javafx-swt.jar      javafx.properties   libglib-lite.dylib  libjfxwebkit.dylib
javafx.base.jar     javafx.swing.jar    libgstreamer-lite.dylib libprism_common.dylib
javafx.controls.jar javafx.web.jar      libjavafx_font.dylib    libprism_es2.dylib
javafx.fxml.jar     libdecora_sse.dylib libjavafx_iio.dylib libprism_sw.dylib
javafx.graphics.jar libfxplugins.dylib  libjfxmedia.dylib   src.zip
javafx.media.jar    libglass.dylib      libjfxmedia_avf.dylib
$ javac -version
javac 12.0.2
$ cd samples-master/CommandLine/Non-modular/CLI/hellofx
$ javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls -d out $(find src -name "*.java")
$ find . -type f
./out/hellofx/HelloFX.class
./out/hellofx/Launcher.class
./src/hellofx/HelloFX.java
./src/hellofx/Launcher.java
```

Up until trying to launch:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode)
$ java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls -cp out hellofx.HelloFX
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
   <stack trimmed>
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
   <stack trimmed>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   <stack trimmed>
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
   <stack trimmed>
```

The research I did led me to think that the native libraries are not found. So I tried to add `$PATH_TO_FX` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DY LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with no better result. Following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985678/migration-to-jdk-11-javafx-11-giving-runtimeexception#comment92877169_52985678) I added `-Dprism.verbose=true` to the command line:

```
$ java -Dprism.verbose=true --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls -cp out hellofx.HelloFX
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_es2 in java.library.path: [/Users/bruno/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
   <trimmed the rest of errors that are essentially the above>
```

So indeed there is a problem of (at least) `libprism_es2.dylib` not being found. I then tried to add `$PATH_TO_FX` to `java.library.path`:

```
$ java -Dprism.verbose=true -Djava.library.path=$PATH_TO_FX --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls -cp out hellofx.HelloFX
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib: code signature in (/Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
   <...>
```

Now the library is found, but is not considered valid.

Comment: Does it work if you create new simple project containing main class with `System.out.println("Hello World")` ?

Comment: For me this version of the JDK and JFX works without problems on the same version of macOS as yours and I don't have to mess around with the libary path. Possible differences: I use the Oracle provided OpenJDK and JavaFX via Maven. Have you checked your environment? Maybe you have defined some variables which interfere with your command line options.

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1211) with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.4 (probably the same was happening with 12.0.2), and native libraries failed to be extracted with the message `no suitable image found...mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned`. Can you try [OpenJDK 12](https://jdk.java.net/12/)?

Comment: @bakero98 Yes, a simple non-JavaFX program works.

Comment: @JoséPereda This is indeed the exact same error. I downloaded the test program mentioned in the issue and I get the same (erroneous) behaviour. Thanks for pointing that. I'll try with OpenJDK 12 asap.

Comment: @JoséPereda And I confirm that everything is working as expected with OpenJDK 12 (as opposed to AdoptOpenJDK 12). Thanks for you help. You may want to turn your comment as an answer, so that I accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your command line:

```
$ java -Dprism.verbose=true --module-path $PATH_TO_FX \
    --add-modules=javafx.controls -cp out hellofx.HelloFX
```

everything looks okay, so it should work fine. In fact, you get it running, until it fails with:

```
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib: \
    dlopen(/Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  \
    Did find: /Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib: \
code signature in (/Users/bruno/try/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib) \
not valid for use in process using Library Validation: \
mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

There is a [bug](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1211) reported to AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.4 about native libraries that cannot be loaded with 11.0.4+11.2 on Mac, and produces the exact same error message.

However, you are running AdoptOpenJDK 12.0.2, and your project works for you with [OpenJDK 12](https://jdk.java.net/12/), so it seems this bugs also extends to AdoptOpenJDK 12.0.2+10.

So while this is fixed, you can use OpenJDK 12. Note that there has been already [reported](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1211#issuecomment-522638784) that 12 fails.

**EDIT**

I can confirm that the latest [11 prerelease](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk11u-2019-08-19-00-56/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_2019-08-19-00-56.tar.gz) for Mac works (it actually says Java version 11.0.5).

The same goes with the latest [12 prerelease](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk12u-2019-08-19-12-15/OpenJDK12U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_2019-08-19-12-15.tar.gz) for Mac, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the released version of AdoptOpenJDK 12.0.2 does not work correctly

```
openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Yes, but the latest prereleases work. See Edit above.