# No window comes up when running javafx application

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx, java-11

Running JavaFX application using VM argument. Program compiles and runs. Using Eclipse on MacOS. When the program runs it shows the java coffee cup logo in the dock, but no window comes up.

I want to be able to run this program successfully. I believe it's an Eclipse configuration issue rather than code.

I had a lot of issues getting JavaFX to run on Eclipse for Mac with the main one being that libraries did not exist and would not import. I was able to get it to work by downloading JavaFX from here (https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), creating a user defined library into my project and running the program with a VM argument: --module-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls. Now the program compiles but I bump into the issue described above.

This post describes the issue I'm having: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7886329

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class SimpleCalculator extends Application
{

    private Label firstValue;
    private Label secondValue;
    private Label sumLabel;

    public void start( Stage myStage) 
    {
        myStage.setTitle( "Simple Calculator");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane();        
        Scene myScene = new Scene( rootNode, 300, 200 );           

        Label firstValue = new Label( "First Value: ");            
        Label secondValue = new Label( "Second Value: ");          
        Label sumLabel = new Label( "Sum is: ");                   

        TextField firstField = new TextField();                    
        TextField secondField = new TextField();                   
        TextField sumField = new TextField();                      

        sumField.setEditable(false);                               

        rootNode.getChildren().addAll( firstValue, firstField, secondValue, secondField, sumLabel, sumField);
        myStage.setScene( myScene );                                                                                        
        myStage.show();                                                                                          
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        launch( args );                                            
    }

}
```

Window pops and shows the labels and fields. This is not happening with my current code.

Comment: Your program works without problems on my Mac. So it is neither a programming nor a general Eclipse/Mac/JavaFX issue. If you have set up your project correctly it should not be necessary to mess arround with the module path on the command line. The only line which is indeed necessary is --add-modules=javafx.controls For further help it would be necessary to know the exact versions of Eclipse, JDK and JavaFX together with their vendors.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I updated the VM argument to --add-modules=javafx.controls. Still get the same issue. Could you advise on what is your project set up? I'm using Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Java jdk-11.0.4.jdk, JavaFX javafx-sdk-11.0.2.

Comment: I also asked for the vendor. There currently seem to be problems with the AdoptOpenJDK distributions for example.

Comment: I created another project with the JavaFX JARs in javafx-sdk-12.0.2 and Java jdk-12.0.1.jdk and it works now! VM argument --module-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-12.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls

Comment: For the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544721/cannot-execute-javafx-sample-on-macos-no-toolkit-found

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem as did people associated with 3 other posts that I saw.

I disabled this option in run configurations of eclipse:
Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT

It then worked perfectly

Comment: That's weird I tried that and got Invocation Target Exception. My window is still nowhere to be seen.Weird.

Comment: I had the same issue, I searched around 10 threads and this is the only one that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue in IntelliJ

My problem was a simple mistake.
When adding a connection to my database I added these lines to the main function in Main class.

```
JDBC.openConnection();
JDBC.closeConnection();
```

But I also unknowingly removed:
`launch();`

So even though you might not have a database in your application, make sure that launch() is still in the main function

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaFX 17.0.2

Compile

```
javac -d . --module-path E:\javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml Shape_Example.java
```

Run

```
java --module-path E:\javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml rame.Shape_Example
```

Comment: Please fix the (markdown) syntax and explain how this works and why it solves the problem.

Comment: You should add more information about the issue