# Amazon Corretto 11 not included jFX

Tags: amazon-web-services, javafx-11, openjfx, openjdk-11

I have download open jFX 11.0.2 version (JavaFX Windows SDK) and Corretto 11.  Is there any way to integrate it into Corretto 11 JDK?

Answer (score 1):

A good start will be [javafx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx). You need to add jfx modules to the module path. To create a customized runtime image that includes and enables jfx modules by default, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52972960/8492667) answer.